# Python tkinter - timer

Tags: python, timer, tkinter, click

I need some help! I'm learning tkinter and I decided to make a game. I made a button and one label, so when you click the button, it will move randomly on screen and label will count your clicks. Now, I need a timer, but I don't know how to make it. The game should be like this: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/2245518/

Here's my code:

```
    from tkinter import *
from random import randint
import 

root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x470')
root.title('Catch The Button - Game')

clicks = 0

def change():
    global clicks
    clicks += 1
    clicksLabel['text'] = 'Clicks: ' + str(clicks) + 180 * ' '
    rand = randint(1,5)

    if rand == 1:
        button.pack(side = LEFT, padx = randint(1, 220), pady = randint(1, 220))
    elif rand == 2:
        button.pack(side = RIGHT, padx = randint(1, 220), pady = randint(1, 220))
    elif rand == 3:
        button.pack(side = TOP, padx = randint(1, 220), pady = randint(1, 220))
    else:
        button.pack(side = BOTTOM, padx = randint(1, 220), pady = randint(1, 220))


clicksLabel = Label(root, text = 'Clicks: 0' + 180 * ' ')
clicksLabel.pack()

button = Button(root, text = 'Catch me  :P', command = change)
button.pack(side = RIGHT, padx = randint(1, 220), pady = randint(1, 220))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `after` method to let a function run periodically. You could make a label which shows the time and write a function that updates it every 100ms and check when time has run out to show the score:

```
time = 20

def update_time():
    global time
    time = time-0.1
    timeLabel.config(text=str(time))
    if time<0.01:
        timeLabel.config(text='0')
        button.pack_forget()
        Label(root, text='You scored {}'.format(clicks), font=('Helvetica', 20, 'bold')).pack()
    else:
        timeLabel.after(100, update_time)
```

In your code (I changed a few other things too) that looks like this

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x470')
root.title('Catch The Button - Game')

clicks = 0
time = 20

def change():
    global clicks
    clicks += 1
    clicksLabel['text'] = 'Clicks: ' + str(clicks)
    rand = randint(1,5)

    if rand == 1:
        button.pack(side = LEFT, padx = randint(1, 220), pady = randint(1, 220))
    elif rand == 2:
        button.pack(side = RIGHT, padx = randint(1, 220), pady = randint(1, 220))
    elif rand == 3:
        button.pack(side = TOP, padx = randint(1, 220), pady = randint(1, 220))
    else:
        button.pack(side = BOTTOM, padx = randint(1, 220), pady = randint(1, 220))

def update_time():
    global time
    time = time-0.1
    timeLabel.config(text=str(time))
    if time<0.01: # Account for rounding errors
        timeLabel.config(text='0')
        button.pack_forget()
        Label(root, text='You scored {}'.format(clicks), font=('Helvetica', 20, 'bold')).pack()
    else:
        timeLabel.after(100, update_time)

clicksLabel = Label(root, text = 'Clicks: 0')
clicksLabel.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=N)

timeLabel = Label(root, text=str(time))
timeLabel.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=N)
timeLabel.after(100, update_time)

button = Button(root, text = 'Catch me  :P', command = change)
button.pack(side = BOTTOM, padx = randint(1, 220), pady = randint(1, 220))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I wanted! :)

Comment: I didn't know it.. XD Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed that with the following code:

```
from Tkinter import * # if using python 3.x
from tkinter import * # if using python 2.x
from random import randint
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x470')
root.title('Catch The Button - Game')

t0 = time.time()
ctime = 0
clicks = 0

def change():
    global clicks
    global ctime
    global t0

    t1 = time.time()
    dt = t1 - t0
    t0 = t1

    ctime += dt
    clicks += 1

    clicksLabel['text'] = 'Clicks: ' + str(clicks) + 180 * ' '
    timeLabel['text'] = 'Time: ' + str(ctime)[:4] + 's' + 180 * ' '

    rand = randint(1,5)

    if rand == 1:
        button.pack(side = LEFT, padx = randint(1, 220), pady = randint(1, 220))
    elif rand == 2:
        button.pack(side = RIGHT, padx = randint(1, 220), pady = randint(1, 220))
    elif rand == 3:
        button.pack(side = TOP, padx = randint(1, 220), pady = randint(1, 220))
    else:
        button.pack(side = BOTTOM, padx = randint(1, 220), pady = randint(1, 220))


clicksLabel = Label(root, text = 'Clicks: 0' + 180 * ' ')
clicksLabel.pack()
timeLabel = Label(root, text = 'Time: 0.00 s' + 180 * ' ')
timeLabel.pack()

button = Button(root, text = 'Catch me  :P', command = change)
button.pack(side = RIGHT, padx = randint(1, 220), pady = randint(1, 220))

root.mainloop()
```

I simply defined a start time and a running time (t0 and ctime respectively). When the button is pressed, the code

```
t1 = time.time()
dt = t1 - t0
t0 = t1
ctime += dt
```

simply adds the time since the last button press to `ctime` and then the `timeLabel` er label updates with the new time (just as how clicksLabel updates).

Diclaimer: I didn't write a timer that visibly increases without clicking the button, as that would require a while loop, exit conditions and constantly updating, whereas your program is structured to only update on click!

Hope this helps